# How to use 'button:active' from a css file to a javascript file

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, pagination

I am making a pagination. When a page is clicked, that particular page should get a certain color and it should stay that color untill another page is clicked. This is not working.

**My css file:**

```
.pagination {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 0.75rem 1rem;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: #282828;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 1rem;
}

.pagination button {
    margin: 0.25rem;
    padding: 0.75rem 1rem;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    
    color: #ededed;
    background-color: #525252;
    /* width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    background: transparent;
    color: #eee;
    border-color: #eee; */
}

.pagination button:hover {
    border-color: #ff92f1;
    color: #ffb7f1;
}

.pagination button:active {
    background-color: #ff52f1;
    color: white;
    border-color: #ff52f1;
    font-weight: 600;
    box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1rem #ff52f136;
}
```

**What I have tried to do:**

```
import React from 'react'
import "../Pagination.css";

const Pagination = ({totalPosts, postsPerPage, setCurrentPage, currentPage}) => {
    let pages = [];

    for(let i = 1; i<= Math.ceil(totalPosts/postsPerPage); i++) {
        pages.push(i)
    }
  return (
    <div className='pagination'>
            {pages.map((page, index) => {
                return (
                    <button
                        key={index}
                        onClick={() => setCurrentPage(page)}
                        className={page == currentPage ? "active" : ""}>
                        {page}
                    </button>
                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
};


export default Pagination
```

So I tried calling active, but I don't know if this is the correct way to do it. Any sugestions that might work?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `button` should have an added `className` of `active` when it is `currentPage`, perhaps the intended selector could be `.pagination button.active`?

Perhaps try use the below selector instead of `:active`:

```
.pagination button.active {
    background-color: #ff52f1;
    color: white;
    border-color: #ff52f1;
    font-weight: 600;
    box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1rem #ff52f136;
}
```

Comment: No luck unfortunately. I have tried to do button.active instead of button:active. But unfortunately it's not working.